# how to transfer data between local and remote server connected via intermediate server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I can login by `ssh -X servA` from `local`, then `ssh -X servB` from `servA`

To copy data from `local` to `servB`, I `scp` files from `local` to `servA`, then from `servA` to `servB`.

Is it feasible to copy files from `local` to `servB` directly and vice versa?

Comment: Yes, read [this](http://sshmenu.sourceforge.net/articles/transparent-mulithop.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nc (net cat) as a proxy for ssh.

So for your example, edit your `~/.ssh/config` file to look like this:

```
Host servB
ProxyCommand ssh -q servA nc servB 22
```

As long as nc is in your path you should now be able to ssh or scp directory to servB

If you don't have nc you can do it with ssh -W if your version is new enough (>= OpenSSH 5.4),

```
Host ServB
  ProxyCommand ssh -W ServB:22 servA
```

Comment: hi, @JohnC, I got an error. "nc: invalid option -- q"

Comment: looks it's forbidden on my server :-( "ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host"

Comment: hmmm, try username@servB.  If nc is there it should work. (also make sure you are using port 22 for ssh)

Comment: still the same problem. Maybe it's impossible for this server.

Comment: @Lee I updated my answer to cover the case where there is no nc. If your ssh is up to date it might solve your problem.

Comment: Hey that's cool @Lee, I forgot about this one.  It's great to know it worked for you finally!  Please don't forget to accept the solution so others will find it.

Comment: I've noticed that there are some slight flag differences across various platforms & versions of `nc`, especially with the flag that tells it to close the connection on EOF from stdin.  Some versions use `-q0`, some versions use `-N0`, some versions use `-c` (and some don't support that option at all).  Be sure to check which one your version supports if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProxyCommand` in ssh config file.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually do (I do it in a Mac machine don't know if it's different from a Windows machine):

Once you have set up connection with any of the servA or servB you can do:

Copy from local to servA or servB:

```
$ scp -P <port-number used>  <file location to copy from> <username_in servA/servB>@localhost:<file location to copy to>
```

NOTE: This works being in your local machine without ssh-ing to any of the servA/servB, just need to establish connection.

or from servA to servB:

```
$ scp -P <port-number used>  <username_in servA>@localhost:<file location to copy from> <port-number used> <username_in servB>@localhost:<file location to copy to>
```

NOTE: I haven't tried this scp from server to server but seems a little bit straight forward.

Just trying to help here.