# SSH tunneling to transfer the data from one data center to another from middle machine

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, rsync, ssh-tunnel

How to create SSH tunneling for below scenario.

I have 3 machines..

```
A. Data Center A VM.
B. Machine at work (middle man).
C. Data Center C VM.
```

So I can SSH from B -> A and from B -> C, but not from A -> C and C->A.

Is there a way to setup an SSH tunnel, so that I can transfer the data from A(Data Center A) to C (Data Center C) using Machine B.
I want to use rsync to transfer the data, please let me know after tunneling how can I use rsync?

In mentioned reply they have a access from A->B-> C. it is possible using that. In My question I have a access from B->A and B->C and I want to copy data from A->C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to transfer data between local and remote server connected via intermediate server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165517/how-to-transfer-data-between-local-and-remote-server-connected-via-intermediate)

Comment: @JohnC question is not duplicate. They have a access from A->B-> C. it is possible using that. In My question I have a access from B->A and B->C and I want to copy data from A->C

Comment: So just use scp A:/path/file  C:/path/file ?

Comment: I tried this 
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx1 "rsync --rsync-path=/opt/rsync/bin/rsync -rvpogtlH ssh /data/VGR root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx2:/shared/" but it doesn't seems to work, as rsync instillation path on one server is different

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8506473/2413778

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, here are the details

The solution is divided in two parts:

1. Following command will create a tunnel between source and
   destination machine. To debug the connection, break this into two
   parts and add verbose status:

   **Run this command on Middle Machine [B. Machine at work (middle man)]**

   $ ssh -v -R 50000:(Ip address of Data Center C VM):22 (IP address of Data Center A VM)
    Example: ssh -v -R 50000:192.168.1.25:22 192.168.1.36

**Note:** To get this working you need to have ssh keys set up correctly between the two remote hosts [Data Center A VM (Source) and Data Center C VM (Destination)], with the private key on source machine and the public key on destination machine.

2. If 1st soltion works, then you'll get a shell access on Source
   machine (Data Center A VM).  Now try the rsync command from Data
   Center A VM.

   It is recommend to do this in a different terminal, so
   the verbose ssh info doesn't get mixed together with the rsync
   status information.

   $ rsync -e "ssh -p 50000" -vuar /opt/source_path localhost:/opt/destination_path

Answer (score 1):

As discussed [here](https://superuser.com/a/686527/332671)

Try the -3 option, as follows:

```
scp -3 user1@remote1:/home/user1/file1.txt user2@remote2:/home/user2/file1.txt
```

The -3 option instructs scp to route traffic through the PC on which the command is issued, even though it is a 3rd party to the transfer. This way, authorization credentials must reside only on the issuing PC, the third party.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I want to copy huge size of directories and use rsync, Here scp won't work for me.

Comment: Once scp is working you should be able to use rsync no problems.  Test with scp first though.

Comment: I tried this solution http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183504/how-to-rsync-files-between-two-remotes  but getting this error "Host key verification failed"

Comment: scp -3 option is not available in my older OS. I think it is available in newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command from machine2-B (the Middleman):

```
ssh user@machine-A "tar cpvf - filename | ssh user@machine-C "tar xpf - -C /destination"
```